# Junit Test case of method that already has a try-catch clause

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to write a test case for the method `setTrailer()` within the class ErParser. `setTrailer()` has try-catch clauses, and in one of its catch clauses, it catches `NullPointerException`. I'm trying to write a Junit test for the case where `setTrailer()` throws and catches a `NullPointerException`, but the test case keeps failing. Is it because I already caught the exception in the method itself? Should I be catching the exception in the test case instead?

The test case:

```
public class TestERParser { 
    @Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
    public void nullSetTrailer() {
        ERParser recCurrParse = new ERParser();
        recCurrParse.setTrailer(null);
    }   
}
```

setTrailer() method within the ERParser Class:

```
public class ERParser {
private static final String TRAILER_E = "GRAND TOTAL";
private static final String TRAILER_R = "TRAILER";
public String trailerRecord; 

/**
 * Constructs an ERParser object.
 */
public ERParser() {
    this.trailerRecord = null;
    this.trailerVals = null;
}
/**
 * Populates the trailerRecord field with the summary (trailer) record of the input file.
 * @param file  Input file
 * @throws NullPointerException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
 */
public void setTrailer(File file) {
    try {
        FileReader fReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader (fReader);
        String currLine = new String();
        readLoop:
            while (bReader.ready()) {
                currLine = bReader.readLine();
                if (currLine.contains(TRAILER_E) || currLine.contains(TRAILER_R)) {
                    break readLoop;
                }
            }
        this.trailerRecord = currLine.trim();
        System.out.println("From setTrailer(): " + this.trailerRecord);
        fReader.close();
        bReader.close();
    } catch (NullPointerException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be catching NPE; you should be avoiding it alltogether. Check for null values and don't have a NPE exception.

Comment: Usually the exceptions are thrown and caught by the caller, that's the best way to do it, the exception MAY mean something outside; imagine that divide by 0 operation was handled and instead of getting the error it returns 0, or 1, or any other value but you wanted to expect that particular case. With Junit you cannot do anything there but expect a call to that method. If you throw any exception then you can expect the exception.

Comment: i dont think you fully understand how to recover from an IOException, just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected you are catching the NPE inside of your code and it is not being propagated. If you expected your users to catch this exception you should remove this code and adorn your method with throws, to the appropiate classes.

```
public void setTrailer(File file) throws Exception {
        FileReader fReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader (fReader);
        String currLine = new String();
        readLoop:
            while (bReader.ready()) {
                currLine = bReader.readLine();
                if (currLine.contains(TRAILER_E) || currLine.contains(TRAILER_R)) {
                    break readLoop;
                }
            }
        this.trailerRecord = currLine.trim();
        System.out.println("From setTrailer(): " + this.trailerRecord);
        fReader.close();
        bReader.close();
}
```

As your code now throws a checked Exception, you will need to update your Junit method slightly, to catch the checked exceptions

```
   @Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
    public void nullSetTrailer() throws Exception {
        ERParser recCurrParse = new ERParser();
        recCurrParse.setTrailer(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can argue about whether or not this catch block means the exception is handled.  I would argue that merely printing the stack trace is not handling anything.  It might be better to add a throws clause to the method signature and let clients decide what to do with exceptions.

If the method is written that way, it's up to you to test it as-written.  You wouldn't have a choice if this was a 3rd party library.

Write the test that throws the exception; succes means `trailerRecord` is set to `null`.

Your code has another flaw: close the streams in a finally block.  You risk not closing the input stream properly as written.

Answer (score 0):

In your test case are expecting a NullPointerException class. If you catch it, the caller class will not get it. Hence, either you can remove the try/catch blocks or you can rethrow the exception after printing stacktrace :

```
catch (NullPointerException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
```

Comment: Generally you'd want to rethrow the existing exception instead of creating a new one.